# MFRC522: Firmware Unknown

Tags: arduino-uno, rfid

Can someone help me what is the meaning of this sketch? It always outputs in the serial monitor:

```
Firmware Version: 0x1C = (unknown)
Scan PICC to see UID, SAK, type, and data blocks...
```

This is the code of the [MFRC522 library](https://github.com/miguelbalboa/rfid) I use:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <MFRC522.h>

constexpr uint8_t RST_PIN = 9;          // Configurable, see typical pin layout above
constexpr uint8_t SS_PIN = 10;         // Configurable, see typical pin layout above

MFRC522 mfrc522(SS_PIN, RST_PIN);  // Create MFRC522 instance

void setup() {
   Serial.begin(9600);   // Initialize serial communications with the PC
   while (!Serial);    // Do nothing if no serial port is opened (added for Arduinos based on ATMEGA32U4)
   SPI.begin();      // Init SPI bus
   mfrc522.PCD_Init();   // Init MFRC522
   mfrc522.PCD_DumpVersionToSerial();  // Show details of PCD - MFRC522 Card Reader details
   Serial.println(F("Scan PICC to see UID, SAK, type, and data blocks..."));
}

void loop() {
   // Look for new cards
   if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent()) {
     return;
   }

   // Select one of the cards
   if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial()) {
     return;
   }

   // Dump debug info about the card; PICC_HaltA() is automatically called
   mfrc522.PICC_DumpToSerial(&(mfrc522.uid));
}
```

Comment: The code is quite well commented, what don't you understand?  The output`Firmware Version:` line is obviously output by `PCD_DumpVersionToSerial()`. Do you get any other output other than that? You should also see `Scan PICC to see...`. Are you not seeing that? Please be more explicit, and include *a few* more lines of output, to illustrate any repetition of output.

Comment: yes it also output but reader does not read the rfid card nor the rfid key , that is why I assumed that was the error

Comment: Try running the `firmware_check` example. In that sketch, it does say that only known versions are supported (`Serial.println(F("Only known versions supported"));`), so your first output line doesn't bode well

Comment: Please add a link to your post, to the library that you are using. Is it this one: https://github.com/miguelbalboa/rfid?

Comment: yes, thats the one I use.

Answer (score 1):

The mention of `unknown` in the output line:

```
Firmware Version: 0x1C = (unknown)
```

isn't a good sign.

Run the `firmware_check` example to verify that first, before trying to run other code.

The `unknown` is output by [line 1302](https://github.com/miguelbalboa/rfid/blob/master/src/MFRC522.cpp#L1302) of [MFRC522.cpp](https://github.com/miguelbalboa/rfid/blob/master/src/MFRC522.cpp):

```
    default:   Serial.println(F(" = (unknown)"));
```

The [`firmware_check`](https://github.com/miguelbalboa/rfid/blob/master/examples/firmware_check/firmware_check.ino) example states on [line 49](https://github.com/miguelbalboa/rfid/blob/master/examples/firmware_check/firmware_check.ino#L49):

```
  Serial.println(F("Only known versions supported"));
```

So, your hardware (i.e. the reader) *may* not be supported.

The only thing I can suggest is try another reader. Also, read the [README](https://github.com/miguelbalboa/rfid/blob/master/README.rst), there maybe some thing there, or contact the author and/or [raise an issue](https://github.com/miguelbalboa/rfid/issues) to see if you can get support for your version of the firmware (`0x1C`) added.

Answer (score 0):

Put a `delay(5)` after

```
mfrc522.PCD_Init();   // Init MFRC522
```

and it will show the correct firmware version.